# Заместить записи одного столбца одной таблицы на записи другого столбца другой таблицы

Tags: access, delphi, sql

Как заместить записи одного столбца одной таблицы на записи другого столбца другой таблицы sql запросом, если даже принимающий столбец пуст? База в access. Программирую в delphi.

Answer (score 1):

Ой не знаю насчет access'а ничего. Но в mysql это делается так:

```
UPDATE `table1` SET `column1` = (SELECT `column2` FROM `table2` WHERE `some_value` =1 LIMIT 1) WHERE `table1`.`id` = 3
```

По идее как-то так. Обратите внимание запрос select должен возвращать точное количество строк, которые вы хотите обновить.

Если записей в таблице вообще нет, то то же самое только с INSERT'ом:

```
 INSERT INTO `table1` (SELECT * FROM `table2` WHERE `some_value` =1)
```

В access видимо что-то похожее должно быть. Или вообще также все.